# How do I call a parseInt method in Main?

Tags: parseint

I'm currently trying to call 2 parseInt methods from main. One converts characters in a char[] to ints and the other just converts String to int.
But I cant figure out the syntax to have main call them.

I tried `parseInt(String conString2);` and `parseInt(char[] conArray);`

I couldnt find anything on google about this either.

```
public class parseInt 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        parseInt(String);
        parseInt(char[] conArray);
    }

    public static void parseInt(char[] conArray)
    {
        System.out.println("Original Charaters 1, 2, 3");
        char[] conArrray = {1, 2, 3};
        int conInt = Integer.parseInt(new String(conArray));
        System.out.println("New ints " + conInt);

    }

    public static void parseInt(String conString2)
    {   
        String conString = "10";
        System.out.println("this number will be converted to int from string " + conString );   
        int conInt2 = Integer.parseInt(conString);
        System.out.println(conInt2);

    }
}
```

Im expecting for it to run those methods but instead it gives the errors "cannot be resolved to variable" on conArray and String. I get "Syntax error, insert ". class" to complete " on the char[].

Comment: Don't include the types when calling `parseInt(conString2)`. Including the type means you're creating something new, not referencing something that already exists.

Comment: That gives me duplicate method